# yii clistview space between items

Tags: php, yii, whitespace

I'm using a CListView in yii like so:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$posts,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'itemsTagName'=>'ul',
    'itemsCssClass'=>'post_list',
    'template'=>'{items}{pager}{summary}',
    'summaryText'=>'Displaying posts {start}-{end} of {count}',
    'separator'=>null,
)); ?>
```

My view file has no spaces or characters at the beginning or end of it, but the html that the listview creates puts a blank line between each item.  Is there any way to get rid of that blank line?

Edit:

My View file:

```
<li><?php 
echo "<article>";
echo "<header class='article-header'>";
echo "<h2>{$data->title}</h2>";
...
A bunch of other stuff here...
...
echo "</article>";
echo "<hr />";
?></li>
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<ul class="post_list"> (an extra blank line here)
<li>A bunch of stuff (item 1)</li> (and here)
<li>A bunch of other stuff (item 2)</li> (here too)
</ul>
```

I can't get the above to format correctly... But it's a ul with li's inside, but there is a blank line between each element.

Comment: Can you post an example of the html that it generates, also your _view.php file?

Comment: i do not see any blank line, but i do see css margin, so what exactly do you mean by blank line?

Comment: i just posted more info and gave a link to the beta site that it's happening on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select `<ul class="post_list">` element on `HTML` tab of `Firebug` and then press `Edit` button above you can see that there is some wild HTML encoded character `&#65279;` that can't be seen in your text editor. Try to delete line breaks or create a new view file instead.